# If I want to require a lib just once, should it be in application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I want to require a lib just once, so I can use it everywhere, should I do this in app_controller.rb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a custom initializer because you might need this library outside a controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think the application_controller.rb is a reasonable place to put the require statement.

Comment: It should go in a new file in config/initializers

Answer (score 0):

Now, using rails 3, either you place the gem inside your `Gemfile`, which will automatically require it. If it is a file under the `lib`-folder, it normally is required automatically. Both these would cover most cases automatically imho.

If you still want to require something explicitly, I would not use the initializers, but I would recommend adding the require-line to your `application.rb`.

Hope this helps.